# How to Fill value= section of form from another section of webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So, right now I have this small unordered list.

```
   <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        <li id="litem1" class="ui-state-highlight">A Comfortable Life</li>
        <li id="litem2" class="ui-state-highlight">An Exciting Life</li>
   </ul>
```

Then, I have series of hidden inputs in a form for sending information to the next page.

```
   <form action="Instrumental_Values1.php" method="POST"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="item1" value="<script getElementById('litem1').innerhtml();></script>"/> 
    <input type="hidden" name="item2" value="<script getElementById('litem2').innerhtml();></script>"/>
   </form>
```

My problem is that my bit of code to try to grab the list item values by ID and make the them equal to "value" in the hidden inputs doesn't work. I need to transfer those list items and make them the "value" in the hidden input.

So essentially, the next page is a php file that is just echoing those values back, like so:

```
   <?php

   $val1=$_POST['item1'];
   $val2=$_POST['item2'];

   echo $val1.' '.$val2;
   ?>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or have an example to share? I have to use PHP to do this, a Javascript solution is not tenable.

Comment: Are you generating your list items using a php for loop?

Comment: No, the list is really 18 items long, but im abstracting and testing with just 2 items to cut down on complexity. (It wasn't necessary to show for the question, but this list has list items that are being dragged and dropped ("sorted") into another empty list with JQUERY UI.

 The PHP is just echoing the list items out in the order they are sorted

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

I've used `.val()`. 
Reference: [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Add `id`s to the inputs:

```
<form action="Instrumental_Values1.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" id="item1" name="item1" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" id="item2" name="item2" value="" />
</form>
```

Add this script to your page:

```
<script>
  $("#item1").val($("#litem1").text());
  $("#item2").val($("#litem2").text());
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not understanding. Are you saying that the $("#item1").val($("#litem1").text());
$("#item2").val($("#litem2").text());

Goes in a seperate <script></script> tag?

Comment: Ahh thank you, I was pretty sure but reading other's code is confusing sometimes for no reason.

Comment: No problem, did it worked for you? If yes please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: It did not actually, I just get the standard php white screen of death with no output

Comment: The php code in your question is the php code of 'Instrumental_Values1.php' right? Can you simply do `echo "test";`?

Comment: Echoing test produces test as a response. But done with my code I get no output

Comment: Could you `var_dump` the both post variables?

Comment: Var Dump on $_POST: 
array(2) { ["item1"]=> string(0) "" ["item2"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: How do you submit the form?

Comment: Form is submitted like so: 



<input type = "submit" value = "Next Page"> 
  </form>

Comment: For me its working perfectly. And my var_dump doesn't return a array. Do you have any other code on the page?

Comment: There is a bit - the unordered list is being (drag and drop) sorted into a (2nd, but empty) list with JQUERY UI. There is a section of JQUERY script that handles the dragging and dropping plus some internal CSS for the page + the JQUERY UI stuff. A few <p> tags that give instructions to the user about dragging and dropping

Comment: How did you do your var_dump? I wasn't familiar with that

Comment: Could you make a fiddle with your whole code? I did the var_dump like this: `var_dump($_POST['item1']);
    var_dump($_POST['item2']);`

Comment: @TSMfan688 I posted another answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using classical javascript here, so following that style this might work:

```
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li id="litem1" class="ui-state-highlight">A Comfortable Life</li>
  <li id="litem2" class="ui-state-highlight">An Exciting Life</li>
</ul>

<form id="theForm" action="Instrumental_Values1.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" id="formItem1" name="item1" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" id="formItem2" name="item2" value="" />
</form>


<script>
//Set Form Value 1
var formItem1 = document.getElementById("formItem1");
formItem1.value = document.getElementById("litem1").innerHTML;

//Set Form Value 2
var formItem2 = document.getElementById("formItem2");
formItem2.value = document.getElementById("litem2").innerHTML;

//Auto submit the form
document.getElementById("theForm").submit();
</script>
```

The idea here is to set your form values in a script tag instead of trying inline JavaScript.  From your original code, it looks like the values in your form would have been a string in the form of `'<script getElementById('litem1').innerhtml();></script>'` instead of the actual list value.  Also, I didn't know how you where sending your form so the last line in the script tag will automatically send the form.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working when implemented, I get no output

Comment: Just to make sure, you're not trying to run the code snippet are you?  It wouldn't as I don't have access to Instrumental_Values1.php? I should have put everything inside a code block ....

Answer (score 0):

You dont't need to add `id`s or `name`s to the elements and you need only one `ul`. The script will do that for you.

**How it works**
It simply writes the content of the `li` items in an array when the order changes and then writes the content to the hidden inputs.

```
<body>
    <ul id="sortable" class="connectedSortable">
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">A Comfortable Life</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">An Exciting Life</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight">A Sense of Accomplishment</li>
    </ul>
    <form id="sortable-form" action="test.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" value="" />
        <br />
        <input type = "submit" value = "Next Page">
    </form>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

        // ADD IDS TO LI
        var litem_id = 1;
        $("#sortable li").each(function(){

            $(this).attr('id', "litem" + litem_id);
            litem_id++;
        });

        // ADD IDS AND NAMES TO INPUTS
        var item_id = 1;
        $("#sortable-form input[type='hidden']").each(function(){
            $(this).attr('id', "item" + item_id);
            $(this).attr('name', "item" + item_id);
            item_id++;
        });


        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            connectWith: "#shopping-cart"
        });

         $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
           stop: function( event, ui ) {

               var values = [];

               $("#sortable li").each(function(){

                   // SAVE ITEMS IN ARRAY
                   values.push($(this).text());

               });

               var i = 0;

               $("#sortable-form input[type='hidden']").each(function(){

                  // WRITE ITEMS TO INPUTS
                  $(this).val( $(values).get(i) );
                  i++;

               });

           }
         });

});
</script>
```